# docker stop command GlassFish

Tags: docker, glassfish

I have container with GlassFish. 
Command to start my container is

`/opt/glassfish4/glassfish/bin/asadmin start-domain --verbose`

When I stop the container with the stop command, it stops with an error. It stops with code 137 (it is destroyed by OOMKiller).

`Exited (137) 3 seconds ago`

I changed the -t parameter of the stop command to 1000, but the result was the same - error code 137

When I run the command

`docker exec -it ecai /opt/glassfish4/glassfish/bin/asadmin stop-domain`

container stops fine with code 0 in 2 seconds.

How to set a standard stop command so that the container stops with code 0?

Answer (score 1):

`docker stop` sends a SIGTERM to the main process, waits a grace period (by default 10 seconds) for the process to stop, and if the process doesn't shutdown itself, it sends a SIGKILL.

The problem with this is that Glassfish terminates abruptly when a SIGTERM is received.

An approach to solve this is create a shell script as entrypoint of your Glassfish image where you can manage the signals received. To do this, you can use a `trap` to do something like the following.

```
#!/bin/bash

_term() {
    /opt/glassfish4/glassfish/bin/asadmin stop-domain
}

trap _term SIGTERM

/opt/glassfish4/glassfish/bin/asadmin start-domain --verbose
```

Hope this helps, good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Glassfish doesn't trap the SIGTERM signal sent by the docker stop command.

So you need an entrypoint script which trap the SIGTERM as described [here](http://blog.milesmaddox.com/2016/10/31/Docker_Shutdown_Hooks/) :

```
#!/bin/bash

function gracefulShutdown {
  echo "SIGTERM trapped : shutting down"
  /opt/glassfish4/bin/asadmin stop-domain
}

trap gracefulShutdown SIGTERM

/opt/glassfish4/bin/asadmin start-domain -v &
wait
```